# How to add filtered view to Ribbon "Add Existing" button

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have a subgrid which is n:n relationship to current record.

I want to add a filtered view to the "Add Existing" button of this subgrid.

Any idea?

(I followed this article which is exactly same as my requirements: http://danielcai.blogspot.com/2011/12/filtered-lookup-for-existing-button-of.html)

Comment: To save some time you can download the visual ribbon editor and skip some of the XML fun :)

Comment: @JonC: Can't skip what Renaud demonstrated below - it's beyond the capability of any existing visual editor I know.

Comment: Correct. It can't do all of that alone. It can however be used to add a button, set it's properties, set what method it calls, what params it takes, display and enable rules.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you have to export a solution containing the entity with the type you want to filter:

In the **customizations.xml** find the **RibbonDiffXml** node and add the following code:

```xml
  <RibbonDiffXml>
    <CustomActions />
    <Templates>
      <RibbonTemplates Id="Mscrm.Templates"></RibbonTemplates>
    </Templates>
    <CommandDefinitions />
```

And in the the **CommandDefinitions** node, add this:

```xml
<CommandDefinitions>
  <CommandDefinition Id="Mscrm.AddExistingRecordFromSubGridAssociated">
    <EnableRules>
      <EnableRule Id="Mscrm.AppendToPrimary" />
      <EnableRule Id="Mscrm.EntityFormIsEnabled" />
    </EnableRules>
    <DisplayRules>
      <DisplayRule Id="Mscrm.AddExisting" />
      <DisplayRule Id="Mscrm.ShowForManyToManyGrids" />
      <DisplayRule Id="Mscrm.AppendToPrimary" />
      <DisplayRule Id="Mscrm.AppendSelected" />
      <DisplayRule Id="Mscrm.CanWriteSelected" />
    </DisplayRules>
    <Actions>
      <JavaScriptFunction FunctionName="addExistingCustomFilter" Library="$webresource:new_yourLibrary">
        <CrmParameter Value="SelectedEntityTypeCode" />
        <CrmParameter Value="SelectedControl" />
        <CrmParameter Value="PrimaryEntityTypeName" />
      </JavaScriptFunction>
    </Actions>
  </CommandDefinition>
  <CommandDefinition Id="Mscrm.AddExistingRecordFromSubGridStandard">
    <EnableRules>
      <EnableRule Id="Mscrm.AppendToPrimary" />
      <EnableRule Id="Mscrm.EntityFormIsEnabled" />
    </EnableRules>
    <DisplayRules>
      <DisplayRule Id="Mscrm.AddExisting" />
      <DisplayRule Id="Mscrm.ShowForManyToManyGrids" />
      <DisplayRule Id="Mscrm.AppendToPrimary" />
      <DisplayRule Id="Mscrm.AppendSelected" />
      <DisplayRule Id="Mscrm.CanWriteSelected" />
    </DisplayRules>
    <Actions>
      <JavaScriptFunction FunctionName="addExistingCustomFilter" Library="$webresource:new_yourLibrary">
        <CrmParameter Value="SelectedEntityTypeCode" />
        <CrmParameter Value="SelectedControl" />
        <CrmParameter Value="PrimaryEntityTypeName" />
      </JavaScriptFunction>
    </Actions>
  </CommandDefinition>
</CommandDefinitions>
```

The code comes from an XML file that you can find in the CRM 2011 SDK and has been modified to call a custom function from a custom Javascript Library.

Then, create the new JS library with the name specified above in the Library attributes.

Add a first generic function:

```js
/*****************************************/
/*                                       */
/*      Add Custom View To Subgrid       */
/*                                       */
/*****************************************/
function addExistingFromSubGridCustom(params) {

    var relName = params.gridControl.getParameter("relName"),
        roleOrd = params.gridControl.getParameter("roleOrd"),
        viewId = "{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001}"; // a dummy view ID

    var customView = {
        fetchXml: params.fetchXml,
        id: viewId,
        layoutXml: params.layoutXml,
        name: params.name,
        recordType: params.gridTypeCode,
        Type: 0
    };

    var lookupItems = LookupObjects(null, "multi", params.gridTypeCode, 0, null, "", null, null, null, null, null, null, viewId, [customView]);
    if (lookupItems && lookupItems.items.length > 0) {
        AssociateObjects(crmFormSubmit.crmFormSubmitObjectType.value, crmFormSubmit.crmFormSubmitId.value, params.gridTypeCode, lookupItems, IsNull(roleOrd) || roleOrd == 2, "", relName);
    }
}
```

and finally, add the function which should be called by the button:

```js
function addExistingCustomFilter(gridTypeCode, gridControl, primaryEntityName) {

// Here you can specify for which entity the filter should be applied.
// For example, filter only when you try to add an existing record to a client.
// In the other cases, you will call the default method.
    if (primaryEntityName != "client" ) {
        Mscrm.GridRibbonActions.addExistingFromSubGridStandard(gridTypeCode, gridControl);
        return;
    }

    // Add some logic to retrieve information needed to filter your view if you want to


    //Update the fetch that will be used by the grid.
    var fetch = '<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false">' +
                '<entity name="...">' +
                '<attribute name="..." />' +
                '<filter type="and">' +
                '<condition ... />' +
                '</filter>' +
                '</entity>' +
                '</fetch>';
    // Add conditions to your fetch xml dynamically

    // Call the generic method with the rights arguments. 
    addExistingFromSubGridCustom({
        gridTypeCode: gridTypeCode,
        gridControl: gridControl,
        fetchXml: fetch,
        name: "My dynamyc custom filtered view!",
        layoutXml: '<grid name="" object="' + gridTypeCode + '"  jump="all_name" select="1" icon="1" preview="0">' +
               // Provide a layout xml ...
              '</grid>'
    });
}
```

Publish everything and it should be ok!

Comment: Hi Renaud, thanks for your reply. I follow the steps and then the "Add Existing" button missing now. I think is the display rules problem. Can you help?

Comment: I replace `<DisplayRule Id="Mscrm.ShowForOneToManyGrids" />` with `<DisplayRule Id="Mscrm.ShowForManyToManyGrids" />` and it works.

Comment: Ah yes indeed it's a many-to-many relationship. I replaced it in my answer. ;)

Comment: Wonderful stuff here - I had no idea this existed! I've favorited.