# CRM Dynamics How to filter views in user side

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have 3 entities like Member, LongList and ShortList. Both lists have many-to-many relationship with Member entity. I add Members to LongLists, and the Members can be added in multiple LongLists.

The user is going to create ShortLists from the Members of a LongList he/she would select. I can create views for filtering the Members according to their membership of a specific LongList, but I can't make this selection in user side, I can only create different views for each LongList created, which is not a good situation as LongLists are also created by users.

Is there a way to let the user decide which List's Members he/she is going to see? It has to work like, one dropdown to select the view "In Long List" and another dropdown to select which LongList.

Comment: Quite a difficult question to understand, but I'm guessing what you want is this... You have 'N' LongLists with various members. You open up a Short List record. You select the list of members (on left navigation or sub-grid). You then click on add new member... and here you want the look-up form that displays to give you the option to select the LongList to filter by?

Comment: Yeah, it's kind of that. I want the user to select the Members from a LongList he can select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is you can't do this without the help of some JavaScript.

There are a few steps you need to take to fulfill this, firstly you cannot add an extra "dropdown" as such to allow the user to select a Long List to filter by. However, what you can do is add some custom views to a lookup window. So your goal would be this: On the lookup form expand the "view" picklist. We can add custom views to this using JavaScript.

Firstly, let me give you an example of how to do this custom view part. For our example I have made the following presumptions:

- That your entities are called `new_member`, `new_shortlist` and `new_longlist`.
- For the purpose of this JavaScript function, I will just show you how we add this to a lookup field, but I expect you will want to hook this up to a button instead of a lookup field.
- Finally, the paramater you pass in will be a longlist entity you retrieved from CRM (using an ajax/odata call or similar). I will (possibly wrongly) presume that you already know how to do this.

The JavaScript to add a custom view will look something like this:

```js
function addCustomLonglistView(longlist) {
    // Create a view id and a view name
    var viewId = "{A2D479C5-53E3-4C69-ADDD-802327E67A0D}";
    var viewDisplayName = longlist.New_Name + " members";

    // Prepare the fetch xml for the lookup view
    var fetchXml =
        '<fetch mapping="logical" count="250" version="1.0">' +
            '<entity name="new_member">' +
                '<attribute name="new_memberid" />' +
                '<attribute name="new_name" />' +
                '<link-entity name="new_longlist" from="new_memberid" to="new_memberid">' +
                    '<filter>' +
                        '<condition attribute="new_longlistid" operator="eq" value="' + longlist.Id + '" />' +
                    '</filter>' +
                '</link-entity>' +
            '</entity>' +
        '</fetch>';
    var layoutXml = '<grid name="resultset" object="1" jump="new_name" select="1" icon="1" preview="1"><row name="result" id="new_memberid"><cell name="new_name" width="300" /></row></grid>';

    Xrm.Page.getControl("new_memberfield").addCustomView(viewId, "new_member", viewDisplayName, fetchXml, layoutXml, true);
    Xrm.Page.getControl("new_memberfield").setDefaultView(viewId);
}
```

This gets you part of the way. The missing piece is how about adding this to a button? That's a bit trickier. Thankfully I found another stackoverflow answer that should answer this for you:

[How to add filtered view to Ribbon “Add Existing” button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8800905/how-to-add-filtered-view-to-ribbon-add-existing-button)

**Update from comments.**

Some links on developer training and the sdk:

- [Developer Training Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23416)
- [SDK - Client Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309637.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your answer Conor. I have never used CRM with another language, so I don't know how to pass the data using AJAX or sth like it; but I'm gonna learn it. The problem is I don't even know where to write the codes. I'm really new at this Dynamics CRM thing and I just do what I'm told to do. Right now, (as far as I know) there is no .NET part of the project. As soon as I figure out where to write codes, I'm gonna try your answer. Thanks again.

Comment: It's mainly going to be JavaScript you're adding to the form that fires off certain form events. My advice is have a look at the developer training kit for CRM and also look through the SDK: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23416, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309637.aspx. I've added these to the answer as well.

Comment: Thanks again Conor. I'm gonna check those out.